# How to add brand logo at grid and product page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gj5f.png]I want to show brand logo on both pages

Comment: Please add more detail

Comment: Brand is attribute of product, right?

Comment: Yes friend  Brand is attribute of product.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php/***********Display Brand Attribute in Product View page************/?>

            <?php
            if($_product->getManufacturer()){
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

                $brand_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
                $brand_id = $_product->getManufacturer();
                $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
                $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$brand_id;

                $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
                $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
                $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brand_id);
                $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
                $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
                $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

                ?>

                <div class="brand_bg">
                    <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand_value; ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $ThumbImage; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php/***********End Brand Attribute************/?>
```